# Google Docs missing

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

Is there a reason why I cannot now see the Google Docs questionnaire that staff accessed regularly and the responses were collated on a spreadsheet.  For some reason all my Google documents just can't be seen anywhere in my Google account

All suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: You probably need to contact your G Suite administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Either you had editing access removed or the file has become orphaned. If you have had access removed, contact your administrator. If it is orphaned in the Drive search field, type: is:unorganized owner:me

Or go to [this site](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6008339?hl=en) and click the magic blue button.